# Special function needed.

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function, diffeomorphism, inverse-problems

For the implementation of a dynamic Radontransform I'm looking for a set of functions $f_\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with very special condtions, where $\alpha$ is in an arbitrary interval of $\mathbb{R}$. The conditions are, that for every $\alpha$ in that interval holds

1. $f_\alpha$ is a diffeomorphism
2. $f_\alpha$ has an explicit inverse
3. $f_\alpha([-2,2])\subset [-2,2]$
4. $f_\alpha$ is not linear for "most" alphas ($f_\alpha(x)=\alpha x+1$ is not valid, but $f_\alpha$ can be linear for a few values of alpha)

I already found $f_\alpha(x)=\alpha(\beta(\alpha)x^3+x)$ for certain intervals of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The inverse is a but ugly but can be given with cardanos method.

I would extremly appreciate any suggestion of other functions.

NOTE:
Ideally you can chose one $\alpha$ in that intervall, such that $f_\alpha(x)=x$

Comment: It seems like you have a lot of options. You can take any easily invertible function (say $x^n$, log, exp, trig, …) and shift and/or stretch it to make the range correct. Then multiply by $\alpha$ for $\alpha \in[-1,1]$.

Comment: Or is it that you can’t control the interval of $\alpha$?

Comment: Even if $\alpha \in\Bbb R$ can take any value, just choose map $f:\Bbb R\to (-1,1)$ and multiply by $f(\alpha)$ instead.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation! I just edited one thing, why it was hard for me to image such a function. But I'm slowly moving to find functions without that optional constraint. I will try implementing the exponential and see if my reconstruction algorithm works ^^. And the intervall can be chosen arbitrary.

Comment: You could also take $g_{\alpha}:[-2,2]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as  $g_{\alpha}(x)=x^3+\beta(\alpha)$ where $\beta:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary, then put $f_{\alpha}(x)=ag_{\alpha}(x)+b$. Now find $a,b$ so that $f(\pm2)=\pm2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does $f_\alpha$ have to be a diffeomorphism on the whole of $\Bbb R$, or just on $(-2,2)\to(-2,2)$? If it's the latter, you could use
$$
f_\alpha(x) = 4\left(\frac {x+2}{4}\right)^\alpha - 2,
$$
for $\alpha\in(0,\infty)$. This is easy to invert (in fact $\left(f_\alpha\right)^{-1} = f_{1/\alpha}$), and $f_1(x) = x$. It's of course just a shifted and scaled version of $x\mapsto x^\alpha:[0,1]\to[0,1]$.

---

The following family might be more elegant/useful, in that $f_\alpha$ is symmetric around the line $y=-x$:
$$
f_\alpha(x) = 4\left(1-\left(\frac{2-x}{4}\right)^\alpha\right)^{\frac1\alpha} - 2.
$$
for $\alpha\in(0,\infty)$. They're modelled after the unit circle in $(p=\alpha)$-norm. We have
$$
f_\alpha^{-1}(x) = -4\left(1-\left(\frac{2+x}{4}\right)^\alpha\right)^{\frac1\alpha} + 2,
$$
and $f_1(x) = x$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it actualy only has to be the latter
Your answer is really helpful, but i think other shifted and scaled versions are needed, as its complex on $(-2,2)$, e.g. $f_{1.5}(-1.5)=-1-0.25i$

Comment: My mistake, I made it $[-1,1]\to[-1,1]$ on accident. See the edit.

Comment: @Dani I added a potentially more elegant family that's symmetric around $y=-x$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will test my implementation with that :)